# non-conformable arrays in chi-square test

Tags: chi-squared

hey there can i please get assistance with the following error
non-conformable arrays
i want to perform a chi-square test but i keep getting an error message
Heres a copy of my output :
rbind(obs.use, exp.use)
1         2        6         7        9
obs.use 300.0000 473.00000 131.0000 300.00000 473.0000
exp.use 545.5172  28.89943 170.1494  35.71839 123.7155
Warning message:
In rbind(obs.use, exp.use) :
number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

> ## step 3: compare observed and expected with a chi-square statistic
>
> (X2.stat <- sum((obs.use - exp.use)^2 / exp.use))
> Error in obs.use - exp.use : non-conformable arrays

I tried it initially with different data and the code ran smoothly with no error